# Get department number from Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, powershell-2.0

I would like to get all the details included in Active Directory properties, But I am not getting the department number.

The PowerShell scripts is:

```
$Properties =
@(
'EmployeeID',
'givenName',
'EmployeeType',
'Departmentnumber'
)

Get-ADUser "Learner" -Properties $Properties |
    select $Properties |
    Export-Csv C:\Users\Learner\Desktop\test.csv
```

The output is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[`departmentNumber`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/a-departmentnumber) is a multi-valued attribute, so you need to replace the `DepartmentNumber` property with a mangled version of itself, e.g. like this:

```
... |
    Select-Object $Properties |
    Select-Object -Include *, @{n='DepartmentNumber';e={$_.DepartmentNumber[0]}} -Exclude DepartmentNumber |
...
```

or like this:

```
... |
    Select-Object $Properties |
    Select-Object -Include *, @{n='DepartmentNumber';e={$_.DepartmentNumber -join ' '}} -Exclude DepartmentNumber |
...
```